# Given a Google Sheet ID, it is possible to get details of the owner of the sheet using Google Sheet APIs?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to parse some data present in google sheets and I want to get the details about the owner of the google sheet as well (Like the owner's name, and maybe email ID as well).
Is it possible to do that by using Google Sheet APIs ?

Comment: by owner do you mean the user who is logged in? the one who authorized your app?

Comment: By owner I mean the person who owns the google sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do it though the google sheets api.  However if you go though the google drive api and do a [file.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) on the file you get something like this.

```
 "owners": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#user",
   "displayName": "XXXXX",
   "photoLink": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhkDDDZulUhea-c-7_eeZFaG8zpOnTHwYJE8=s64",
   "me": false,
   "permissionId": "XXXXX",
   "emailAddress": "XXXXX@gmail.com"
  }
 ],
```

Drive and sheets use the same scopes so you shouldn't need to authorize any additional scope to use the drive api. You will just need to create a drive service object similar to the one you have for sheets now.

```
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```

pro tip with file.get makes sure you set `fields = *` or `id, owners`

Comment: What does file in file.get refer to ?

Comment: File.get is a method in google drive api which will return the information on a file. Your sheet is a file. Just pass it the sheet id.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by DalmTo, I could get the details by using Google Drive APIs.

After creating a drive service, the following code would get the owner details -

```
response = service.files().get(fileId=googlesheetid,fields='owners').execute()
```

response would contain data like this -

```
{"owners": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#user",
   "displayName": "XXXXX",
   "photoLink": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhkDDDZulUhea-c-7_eeZFaG8zpOnTHwYJE8=s64",
   "me": false,
   "permissionId": "XXXXX",
   "emailAddress": "XXXXX@gmail.com"
  }]}
```